# Serialize stdext::hash_map using boost serialization library

Tags: c++, hashmap, boost-serialization

I want to serialize a hash map to a file and de-serialize it later on.

```
#include <boost/serialization/hash_map.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>
#include <hash_map>

class A: virtual public B {
 public:
     friend class boost::serialization::access;
     stdext::hash_map<std::string, myClass> myClassHashTable; 
     template <class Archive>
     void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
     {
        ar & myClassHashTable;
     }
};

void A::serializedToDisk()
{
      boost::filesystem::path finalPath(SOME_CONSTANT);
      // code to create  boost::filesystem::ifstream ofs object
      boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
      oa << myClassHashTable;
}
void A::restoreFromDisk()
{
     boost::filesystem::path finalPath(SOME_CONSTANT);
    // code to create  boost::filesystem::ifstream ifs object
      boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
      ia >> myClassHashTable;
}
```

But I am getting an error as -

> error C2039: 'serialize' : is not a member of 'stdext::hash_map<_Kty,_Ty>'

I searched online for this error but didn't get much help. Also, I checked in my boost installation `serialization/hash_map.hpp` does have a `serialize()` function in it. The same code worked for serialization of `std::deque`. Can anyone tell me how should I change it to make it compile?

Comment: Not quite what you want, but Google Sparsehash library maps come with some built-in serialization support, though completely separate from Boost serialization.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764249/c-boost-serialization-error-for-hash-map-with-custom-objects-as-key/23768271#23768271

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First at all , insert **`#define BOOST_HAS_HASH`** in top of your code .

This  change your compilation error to :

**“error C2039: 'resize' : is not a member of 'stdext::hash_map<_Kty,_Ty>'”**. :D

Next, if you comment your restoring function, you'll see your code WORK fine and output ! < Good >

But the problem is about an incompatibility between compilers .
Unfortunately, the implementation of **`hash_map`** is different in 'MSVS' and 'GCC' and the `resize` is one example of this difference .

---

Next to resolve this new problem, 
just `#include boost/serialization/map.hpp`
and comment `s.resize(bucket_count);` in `hash_collections_load_imp.hpp` ( where it error )