# How to serialize/deserialize with boost std::vector of boost::unordered_map

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

How to serialize/deserialize with boost std::vector of boost::unordered_map like

```
vector<boost::unordered_map<uint64_t, Person* > *> town;
```

which represents town. All pointers are row on heap created with new. Is possible to deserialize on easy way without refactoring code to use shared_ptr ?
Person also has function also

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & archive, const unsigned int version){
...
}
```

Comment: Look like this is a problem which have been posed to you, -- you probably need to reformulate the question, including how you have attempted to solved it and then somebody can help you fix your attempt on a solution.

Comment: Boost.Serialization [automatically handles pointers](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#pointers). As long as `Person` is serializable, then `Pointer*` is no issue at all. What problem are you encountering?

Comment: @ildjarn Problem is when I want to deserialize I need all persons to be on heap same as all unordered_maps.

Answer (score 1):

unordered_* are not yet supported in Boost Serialization.

Either add the support or use the (deprecated) GCC hash_* containers

A sample of how to add support is in this answer of mine: [C++ Boost.Serialization error for hash_map with custom objects as key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764249/c-boost-serialization-error-for-hash-map-with-custom-objects-as-key/23768271#23768271)

Answer (score 0):

Boost has already supported the `unordered_set` and `unordered_map` since the version 1.5.6. You can just include the header file.

```
#include <boost/serialization/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unordered_set.hpp>
```